# Group by is taking very long time in SQL Query in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, query-optimization

When I use  `group` in my query to get the Sum of few columns, it starts taking too much of time .

Example : -

```
SELECT  
    A.ID PROJECT_ID,
    REGION.LEVEL2_NAME REGION,
    A.LOCATION LOCATION,
    A.DEPT DEPT,
    REPLACE(A.ROLE_NAME, ',', '') ROLE_NAME,
    A.MONTH_START,
    TO_CHAR(A.MONTH_START,'MON YYYY') MONTH_LABEL,
    Sum(A.value1),Sum(A.value2)
FROM 
(/here is my Select Query which gives flat data with some 2 UNION Queries/ )A
 INNER JOIN table REGION ON A.column1= REGION.column1
GROUP BY  
    A.ID, 
    A.ROLE_NAME, 
    A.LOCATION, 
    A.DEPT, 
    A.UNIT_OF_MEASURE,
    REGION.LEVEL2_NAME, 
    A.MONTH_START
```

Please advice .

Comment: How many rows does your subquery retrieve?

Comment: Hi John , The count is little huge , i.e. - 40 Million

Comment: Can you generate an execution plan with runtime stats. You can do this by; alter session set timed_statistics=all; <run your query>. select * from table( dbms_xplan.display_cursor( null, null, 'ALLSTATS LAST' ) );

Comment: So you're doing analytics on a 40 million row set. What is "too much time"? How long do you expect it to take?

Comment: It was keep on running , however the subquery flat data comes up quickly in seconds in SQL developer .

Comment: Perhaps SQL Developer didn't fetch all 40 million rows when you tested it without GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0):

What is meant by "when I added a group by, it started taking a long time"?  Given additional information in the comments, I would expect it to take a long time.  Before you added the group by, you were running a query that probably returned fairly quickly as it executed the query then fetched a subset of rows, 200-500, depending on your client tool.  When you add the group by, the database will have to read in all rows for the query because it will have to aggregate all rows before any single row could be returned.  At 40 million rows, this may take a while.

I'm new to posting here.  But my comment on the question would be that you need to provide additional information when you are looking for performance help.  The full query would help, you've left out a big part of the query.  The data model, some sample data, and some additional data volumes on the tables involved.  Scrub as needed to protect the information.

Comment: I agree with your explanation - I am just posting my query . Please advice if any other way it  can be written  to improve its performance .

Comment: See my answer/comment.  You have not provided me with enough information for me to help you.  You have also not provided additional insight as to how fast you think this should return.  As I said, your select will be fast because it is quickly returning the first set of rows, but not the entire set of rows, so it appears quicker than it really is.  But when you add the group by/aggregation, you are now waiting for the whole thing.

Comment: I am not able to post my entire query here .

Comment: Try this, remove the group by and wrap the base query with a simple count, like this...   select count(*) from (original query); ... and see how long that runs.  This would be a better comparison than just running the original query alone.

Comment: The total count - 10183462 and it took 74.995 sec after doing count(*) from the base query .

Comment: What I noticed that , there is one Left join condition with  <Mat View> in the original query which seem to be causing performance issue  . When I replaced this left join with inner join - the query gives me quick result . Please advice around this .

Comment: Count(*) of Original Query without Group by -
------------------------------------------------------------
Left Join with Mat View  - Count(*) = 49654900, Execution  Time =645 secs, 
Inner Join with Mat View - Count(*) = 10183462 , Execution Time = 74 Secs

Comment: So, your query that was quick in Sql Developer is really taking almost 11 minutes to return when it has to look at all ~50 million rows.  How does this compare to the group by version?  And, also think about what you are trying to ask me to help you with, the inner query that you've provided no information on.  How do you expect the community to help you?

Comment: So for fear of repeating myself: Can you generate an execution plan with runtime stats. You can do this by; alter session set timed_statistics=all; <run your query>. select * from table( dbms_xplan.display_cursor( null, null, 'ALLSTATS LAST' ) );